# How do I immediately throw a DataAccessException when testing a 5xx response using MongoTemplate and Testcontainers without waiting for the timeout?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, testcontainers, mockmvc

I'm trying to write tests that cover MongoDB being unavailable. In my code, to handle this event, I catch a `DataAccessException` and throw my own custom `ServiceUnavailableException` returning a 503 response code.

Using Testcontainers and MongoDBContainer / MongoTemplate, how do I avoid the 30-second timeout, when I stop the MongoDBContainer, to simulate Mongo being unavailable?

Currently, the 30-second timeout makes the test impractical to run. I want to be able to immediately throw a `DataAccessException` and assert a 503 response.

My test looks like this:

```java
    @Test
    void savingDocumentToDbReturns503() throws Exception {
        mongoDBContainer.stop();
    
        mockMvc.perform(post("/endpoint")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isServiceUnavailable());
        
        mongoDBContainer.start();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to make an mock respose ?

Comment: Yes but as it is an integration test I don't want to make the MongoTemplate object a mock object (or a MockBean).

Comment: i think the goal of this test-case is to check if  throwing exception is `ServiceUnavailable`.  and it`s ok to mock this one.

Comment: I see. Would you say that unit tests would adequately cover this scenario? I thought I would assert that nothing persisted to Mongo after the 503 was returned to cover all bases. Would you say that is unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, an unit test in this scenario will be enough, yest, it`s unnecessary, because when a time out is throwing it mean that something went wrong while  access a DB it show that nothing was persisted.

Comment: Hi, you can simulate networking failures using Toxiproxy module. This blogpost can help you https://www.atomicjar.com/2023/03/developing-resilient-applications-with-toxiproxy-and-testcontainers/